# Does there exist a $3$-variable word $w$ and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in S_n$ with $w(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\mathrm{id}$ and three other properties?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

**Question**: For some $n$, does there exist a three-variable [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(group_theory)) $w(x,y,z)$ over the symmetric group $S_n$ and three non-identity permutations $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in S_n$ with the following properties?
\begin{align*}
w(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) &= \mathrm{id} \\
w(\alpha',\beta,\gamma) &= \alpha' & \text{ for all } \alpha' \in S_n \setminus \{\alpha\} \\
w(\alpha,\beta',\gamma) &= \beta' & \text{ for all } \beta' \in S_n \setminus \{\beta\} \\
w(\alpha,\beta,\gamma') &= \gamma' & \text{ for all } \gamma' \in S_n \setminus \{\gamma\}
\end{align*}

I'm guessing this is not possible, as it seems we're putting too many constraints on the word.

I'm brainstorming an idea for a secret sharing scheme in which we can identify who submits false shares.  For the application I have in mind, $n$ would be around $20$ or so.  I'm not sure if the scheme I have in mind will work; there's a lot of matters that would need to be simultaneously resolved (this being one of them).

Comment: Even satisfying one of the three bottom equations seems very hard, if not impossible. This is equivalent to asking:
Given a word $w(x)$ in a variable$ x$ and elements of the group, can we have that $w(a)=a$ for all but one element of the group?



I feel the answer is already no, unless we have $w(x)=x$.

Comment: Here is a sketch of a beginning of a proof.

Suppose $w(x)$ contains just one instance of $x$, so $w(x)=w_1 x w_2$.
Then $1=w(1)=w_1w_2$, so $w(x)=x^{w_2}=x$ and $w_2$ is central so $w_2=1$. (I'm assuming $n\geq 3$ throughout, the case $n=2$ can be done directly.)

Comment: Suppose w(x) contains two instances of $x$, so $w(x)=w_1 x w_2 x w_3$.
We have $1=w(1)=w_1w_2w_3$, and  $w_1^{-1}=w(w_1^{-1})=w_2w_1^{-1}w_3$. Combining these two, we get $w_1^{-1}=w_2w_1^{-1}w_2^{-1}w_1^{-1}$ hence $w_1=1$ and so on...

(Of course, I skipped the possibility that $a=w_1^{-1}$ is the unique value for which $w(a)=a$ does not hold, but this could also be handled with some casework.)

Perhaps one could keep going, dealing with more instances of $x$, using induction or something.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a stupid answer: As there are no constraints on $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ you may set $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = id_n \in S_n$ and take the word $w(x,y,z) = xyz$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  The answer's not the problem: I should have thought of that for my question.  I'm assuming $\alpha \neq \mathrm{id}$, $\beta \neq \mathrm{id}$, $\gamma \neq \mathrm{id}$, but I didn't state it (I better add it in: sorry).  [I'm still worried there might be a trivial example though.  Hmm...]